Spyne define a function that accepts array of complex types
I am trying to make a SOAP function on my spyne server that follows this structure.
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap-env:Body>
    <test_function xmlns:ns0="Test">
      <resource>
        <item>
          <material>gold</material>
        </item>
        <item>
          <material>silver</material>
        </item>
      </resource>
    </test_function>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>

Code that is closest to work is this
class Material(ComplexModel):
    material = Unicode

class Resource(Array): # Changing to ComplexModel doesn't affect
    item = Material

class Soap(ServiceBase):
    @rpc(Resource)
    def test_function(ctx, resource):
        print(resource)
        return "Yes"


app = Application(
    [Soap],
    tns='Test',
    in_protocol=Soap11(),
    out_protocol=Soap11()
)
application = WsgiApplication(app)

I make requests with zeep and code of client looks like this
params = {
    "resource": [
        {"item": {"material": "gold"}},
        {"item": {"material": "silver"}}
    ]
}

...

with zeep_client as client:
    msg = client.create_message(
        client.service, 'test_function', **params)


But my request have only one <item>, second one is missing.
I tried to play Array in different places but they either makes code not working (unexpected arguments errors) or doesn't change anything.
Decorating function with @rpc(Array(Resource)) leads to
`TypeError: {Test}ResourceArray() got an unexpected keyword argument 'item'. Signature: `Resource: {Test}Resource[]`

